# How to solve SocketExceptions in Azure EventHub while sending messages

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

**Setup:**

- Azure EventHub which is scaled to use 2 partitions and 1 throughput unit
- Connection using AMQP
- NETCore 2.1
- No Proxy, No VNets
- Service is running in a ServiceFabric Cluster (5 Nodes)

**Code**

```
// ###########
// 1. Try

var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var message in messages)
{
    var t = eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
    tasks.Add(t);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();

// ###########
// 2. Try

var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
foreach(var message in messages)
{
    try 
    {
        await eventHubClient.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
    }
    catch(Exception)
     {
        await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    }
}
await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
```

**Problem**
When sending to this EventHub thousands of messages (even more than this scaling can process) I get a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` from the AMQP implementation (`Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`).

Not all messages will be processed and the exceptions will stay and will occured until I restart the nodes (happening on all Nodes)

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient+d__32.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c)
>   [...]
>   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   My.Company.Data.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubSender+d__5.MoveNext
>   (My.Company.Core.Data.Azure, Version=1.2018.9.142, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null)

**Update**
I also tried to dispose the `eventHubClient` if this error occured with no success, same exception occurs.

Comment: Can you include the method signature of the method that SendAsync is called from?

Comment: @RickRainey I have updated my question with more code

Comment: I assume that it reaches the max of  number of AMQP connections per eventhub namespace. The limitation is 5000 connections. `Subsequent requests for additional connections will be rejected and an exception is received by the calling code.` For more information please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas).

Comment: @TomSun Was my first thought too... so I added the `.CloseAsync`-Part. Without success...